# Convert String.concat() to Template String

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to rewrite some Scripts from a colleague.

We're using ES2015+ so we're able to use Template Strings, however almost all of his String Concatinations are made with the .concat() function.

Is there an automatic way to convert the following code?

Original Code:

```js
const logName = "example"
const errorMessage = "error";
console.log("Error: ".concat(errorMessage));
console.log("".concat(logName, ": ").concat(errorMessage));
```

Converted Code:

```js
const logName = "example"
const errorMessage = "error";
console.log(`Error: ${errorMessage}`);
console.log(`${logName}: ${errorMessage});
```

For String concatinations with `"" + errorMessage` i have no issues, eslint is automatically able to transform them to `` `${errorMessage}` ``.

Comment: Well, there's none built into [tag:javascript]… some text editor search and replace might do, or you need a more complex parse-and-transform tool. This is all rather too vague and/or broad.

Comment: Sadly i thought as much, I'll leave the question open in case someone else faced this Problem already, other than that i guess Search and Replace is the way to go

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/facebook/jscodeshift . It should be possible to write a codemod for this. You can play around with it at https://astexplorer.net . Disclaimer: I am / was working on both projects.

Comment: There is [lebab](https://github.com/lebab/lebab) which is the opposite of babel. But I don't think it supports `concat`. When I tried it here https://lebab.unibtc.me/editor, only concatenation with `+` is converted